# Word metric for abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

If $G$ is finitely generating group with generating set $S=\lbrace s_1,..., s_n\rbrace$. Then we need $S$ to be a symmetric set in order to define the word metric.

Is it possible that, if $G$ is abelian than condition on $S$ to be symmetric, can be drop? As in case of integers, group is cyclic but we can still define the length. 
Is it possible, when $G$ is abelian than we can simply take the length of $g\in G$ to be the  $infimum$ of $sum$ of modulus of $powers$ of $s_i's$ where $i\in \lbrace 1,..., n\rbrace$ and $infimum$ is taken over distinct representation's of $g$.

Mainly the problem is:
Let $S=\lbrace s_1,..., s_k\rbrace$ (need not symmetric set i.e we do not need $a\in S$ if and only if $a^{-1}\in S$) be a finite generating set for abelian group $G$. Then every element of $g\in G$ can be written as a representation $R_g=s_{1}^{n_1}...s_{k}^{n_k}$ where $n_{i} \in Z$.
Define $R^{+} _{g} =|n_1|+...+ |n_k|$ and  length of $g$ to be$L_g= inf_{R_g} R^{+}_{g} $. 
Clearly, infimum exist. 
Define metric as $d(g, h) =L_{g^{-1}h}$
I am claiming that for such definition of word length on finitely generated abelian group, $d$ defines a metric.

Comment: What is a symmetric set?  If I just take an arbitrary set of generators, why can't I just define the associated word metric?

Comment: @lulu Here, $S$ being symmetric means $S = S^{-1} := \{ x^{-1} \mid x \in S \}$. This assumption is needed to prove $d(g,h) = d(h,g)$; see the Wikipedia article about it (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric).

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht  Oh, thanks.  Never heard that use of "symmetric" before.

Comment: So, the comment from @S.vanNigtevecht seems to settle the point...you need the condition even if $G$ is abelian.  Take $\mathbb Z$ with the generators $S=\{1,-2\}$.  Then $d(1,0)=1$ as the word "$1$" describes $1$.  But look at $d(0,1)=|-1|$.  the shortest word in $S$ that gets $-1$ is $-2+1$, so $|-1|=2$.

Comment: I mean take distinct representation of element. By definition in above problem and your example @lulu. I mean $-2=(1)^(-2)$ so possible length of $-2$ is 2 as $1\in S$ and $-2=-2$ also generating element so length of $-2$ is $min(2,1)=1$. Now, $d(0,1)=1^(-1)$. So by definition in problem length is still same. So, no problem occur.

Comment: I don't understand.  if you are adding the inverses of generators back into the generating set then $S$ is symmetric, in the sense you mean.  There is no word of length $1$ in my generators that gets you to $-1$.

Comment: Let $S=\lbrace s_1,..., s_k\rbrace$ (need not symmetric set i.e we do not need $a\in S$ if and only if $a^{-1}\in S$) be a finite generating set for abelian group $G$. Then every element of $g\in G$ can be written as a representation $R_g=s_{1}^{n_1}...s_{k}^{n_k}$ where $n_{i} \in Z$.
Define $R^{+} _{g} =|n_1|+...+ |n_k|$ and  length of $g$ to be$L_g= inf_{R_g} R^{+}_{g} $. 
Clearly, infimum exist. 
Define metric as $d(g, h) =L_{g^{-1}h}$
I am claiming that for such definition of word length on finitely generated abelian group, $d$ defines a metric.

Comment: Yes, but you are wrong.  My example shows that (I believe).  I gave an example of a generating set $S=\{1,-2\}$ for $\mathbb Z$.  Perfectly good generating set, but the word function does not define a metric.  That's because $d(g,h)\neq d(h,g)$.  Specifically I showed that $d(1,0)=1\neq 2=d(0,1)$.  You need the symmetry condition to get a metric.

Comment: No, according to my definition, minimum length must be $1$ for any non identity element. As, $d(1,0)=L_{1^{-1} 0}=L_{1^{-1}}=1$, for representation $1^{-1}$, Length is $|1|=1$ and  $d(0,1)=L_{0^{-1} 1}=L_1=1$ for representation $1^{1}$, as operation is additive here.